# Slick 2D - .playing() boolean messed up

Tags: java, audio, slick2d

I am creating a game with Slick 2D.

I want an animation to play as a sound is playing. It is all working fine, the sound plays, the animation plays. However, after this point, the animation will play if ANY sound plays. What is going on?

```
if (sound1.playing()) {
            exA.draw(700, pY); // Animation plays if sound2.playing()
        } else {
            g.drawImage(idlePic, 700, pY); // Regular picture is drawn if no sound is playing.
        }
```

Here is where sound2 plays:

```
if (cvX.length >= 1) {
                for (int j=0;j<cvX.length; j++) {
                    if (checkCatch(cvX[j], cvY[j]) && amount < 10) {
                        cvX = removeElement(cvX, j);
                        cvY = removeElement(cvY, j);
                        amount++;
                        purity++;
                        sound2.play(1.0f, .25f);
                    }
                }
            }
```

cvX and cvY hold the coordinates of every object. The checkCatch method takes one set of coordinates, and compares it to the player's coordinates. If they are close enough, it deletes the object, adds 1 to amount, adds 1 to purity (score systems), and plays the sound.

Comment: exA.draw(700, pY); will only execute if sound1.playing() is true, maybe share some code where you start and stop your sounds.

Comment: Alright, added it. Thanks. However, is there a spot where I should be stopping my sounds?

Comment: You can try using a boolean variable to decide wheter play your animation or not, however you will still have something wrong with sound1.playing() since it should not return true when is not playing. I'd like to see what happens with your sound1 and hopefully I could help more.